# How to add a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, parameters

Im studying Ruby on Rails and found one question which I can't resolve.

Description:
I have a Ticket and Comments. One Ticket should have many comments. All comments which belong to a ticket should be listed in the Ticket's "show" view. There is also a text field and a button "add new comment". After adding a comment should be rendered the view "show" of the current ticket.

The problem:
How to send the current ticket's id to the Comments Model to get saved a comment and how to render (or redirect?) the view "show" of a Ticket from the Comment's method "create"?

my files:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

---

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
end
```

---

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
......
```

---

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:text))
    **@comment.ticket_id = @current_ticket_id** #The problem is here
    @comment.save

    **redirect_to ticket_path(params[:id])** #and here
  end
```

---

```
<h1>Ticket details</h1>

<%= @ticket.number %></br>
<%= @ticket.title %></br>
<%= @ticket.text %></br>

<h3>Comments:</h3>
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
<%= f.label "Your comment:" %>
<%= f.text_field :text %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
 </br>

<% @ticket.comments.all.each do |comment| %>
<p><%= comment %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the ticket id as a hidden field in the form, as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Your comment:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ticket_id, value: @ticket.id %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then access it from the controller as follows:

```
@comment.ticket_id = params[:ticket_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form is displayed in your ticket show view, you can pass in the ticket params and build the comment straight from the form. In the controller, you can set the ticket by the :ticket_id, not by finding the ticket :id so rails doesn't get confused.

On the ticket show:

```
<%= form_for([@ticket, @ticket.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add Comment' %>
<% end %>
```

In the comments controller:

```
def create
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
    @comment.ticket_id = @ticket.id

    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = 'Comment Posted'
        redirect_to :back
    else
        @comment.errors.each do |attr, msg|
        flash[:warning] = msg
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are using nested resources in your routes.rb that is:

> resources :tickets do
>
> resources :comments
>
> end

in your controller create action all you have to do is update your create action a bit.
from

> @comment.ticket_id = @current_ticket_id

to

> @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
>
> @comment.ticket = @ticket

make sure your params you accept the tickects attributes i.e update

this

> params.require(:comment).permit(:text)

to this

> params.require(:comment).permit(:text, ticket_attributes:
> [:tickect_id])

Hope that helps